# Filter out rows between two values

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have a problem regarding filtering out some rows.

Sample dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3"), description= c("Start", "Something", "Final", "Start", "Some Other Thing", "Final", "Start", "Final"), timestamp = c("2017-07-26 23:41:16", "2017-07-27 20:23:16", "2017-07-29 07:06:53", "2017-07-24 04:53:02", "2017-07-25 10:27:02", "2017-07-26 16:51:43", "2017-07-13 08:33:05")))
```

Now I want to delete all groups where no other values between description = "Start" and description ="Final" exist. And this should be done for each id group. In this example it would be the group with the ID 3.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you just use `filter(df, description %in% c("Start", "Final")`?

Comment: unfortunately not. I think I was maybe a little bit imprecise. I want groups filtered out, that have nothing between "Start" and "Final", but I want groups, that have "Start", "Final" and other descriptions in between. I edited the description and the example. Sorry for confusion!

Answer (score 0):

If we convert `timestamp` to `datetime`, then we can just sort the data and use `cumsum` to do what you want (I think).

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(timestamp = lubridate::as_datetime(timestamp)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(id, timestamp) %>%
  mutate(tracker = cumsum(description %in% c("Start", "Final"))) %>%
  filter((tracker %% 2 == 1) & description != "Start")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#> # Groups:   id [2]
#>   id    description      timestamp           tracker
#>   <fct> <fct>            <dttm>                <int>
#> 1 1     Something        2017-07-27 20:23:16       1
#> 2 2     Some Other Thing 2017-07-25 10:27:02       1
```

Comment: my expected outcome would be all rows with the ID 1 and 2 in the example df.

Answer (score 0):

So the following might be one solution of your problem.

```
Test = df %>% aggregate(description~id, data=., FUN=function(x) c(count=length(x)))
Test$id = as.factor(Test$id)
df = inner_join(df, Test, by = "id")
df = df[df$description.y > 2, ]
```

The idea is to filter out all groups that only have two descriptions (Start, Final) via an inner_join. The output is

```
> df
  id    description.x           timestamp description.y
1  1            Start 2017-07-26 23:41:16             3
2  1        Something 2017-07-27 20:23:16             3
3  1            Final 2017-07-29 07:06:53             3
4  2            Start 2017-07-24 04:53:02             3
5  2 Some Other Thing 2017-07-25 10:27:02             3
6  2            Final 2017-07-26 16:51:43             3
```

Is that what you had in mind?

Answer (score 0):

another solution

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(n = n()) %>% 
  filter(n != 2)
```